# Where should I store a client secret in a javascript application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Where should I store a client secret in a JavaScript application to **prevent other users** from getting access to it? My particular use case is an AngularJS SPA.

The client secret is a guid which is generated at login and passed back to the client, expires after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Considering the nature of my secret key, should I even care?

Comment: Can always use `localStorage`

Comment: What do you mean by "other users"? What exactly are you trying to guard against?

Comment: You send it over HTTPS and make sure that you don't have any XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'm trying to make sure someone can't jack my user's session and gain their privilages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

One: You can't. It's on their side, anyone with access (to the computer while that user is logged in) and knowledge will be able to see it. As well as anyone that intercepts the transmission from client to server (if your not using https).

Two: It's not necessary if you are implementing it correctly.

- Meaning will it ever be valid again, after it expires, or is it a one off*?
- Is it authenticated against the other half on your server?

*By one off, I mean a GUID is supposed to be globally unique. Are you using the same GUID each time for each user or are you scrapping it and the next time assigning them a new one? If the first you have an issue.

If your doing all those things then you really don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I'm having trouble translating your second thing into concrete actions. Technical constraints mean that the client secret will act like a session token, where the expiration is extended with activity. If you know how I can implement the client secret as a one off, that would be appreciated. I am doing the second point. I don't see how the third point is relevant.

Comment: @ton.yeung Edited, sorry about third point I misread something in your original post.

Comment: I'm generating a guid every time a user logs in. Every time an authenticated user hits the api, I check the token, and if it exist, I extend the timeout. After the timeout, the token is deleted, and the user has to reauthenticate, getting a new GUID. Everything is behind ssl. I should be good?

Comment: @ton.yeung one more thing. if the GUID is still active, could someone else who knew the GUID use it to connect to your api and do anything? If they can't then you are as safe as you can be when using a GUID on the clients side.

Comment: yep, they can, so far I haven't found any way around that. which is why I'm worried about not letting any other user be able to get it.

Comment: @ton.yeung Ah, I knew there was a reason for my third point. You need to connect on the server the GUID with something unique to that user. Like their password hash. It requires 2 steps, you have to check that the GUID is not only there but it is the ***current*** GUID of your logged in user. If a valid GUID is in the api call but it isn't being passed with the correct *User* information. Then you reject it.

Comment: I'm doing that, the list of guids is stored with the username that its generated for. The problem is that if someone gets the guid for an ACTIVE session, it doesn't matter, because since the session is active they get all the privileges of the user they jacked.

Comment: @ton.yeung of course if they highjack that users session. There is nothing you can do about that, what I'm talking about is, could they, on a different computer, use that GUID to imitate that user, without knowing the users credentials? So hypothetical, someone leaves to go to bath room will be back soon, hacker hops on gets GUID out of javascript and then bails cause the user is back. Could that hacker then use the GUID to do 'bad things'?

Comment: they can do as much bad things as the user's access allows them to. I don't see how to get around that.